# Как запусть скрипт PS1 (PowerShell) из кода C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Есть необходимость запустить скрипт ps1 из кода C#, по нажатию кнопки. Как это можно реализовать, если скрипт лежит в bin\Debug или в ресурсах (тут непринципиально, подстроюсь). Спасибо!

Comment: Первая [ссылка гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) по запросу `c# run powershell script`. Потратил на это пол минуты, а вы уже час сидите и ждете ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в проект PowerShell SDK и воспользоваться примером по ссылке из комментария к вопросу